# Is there a term for scifi set in space that isn’t space opera?

Tags: terminology, genre

The term “space opera” implies far more than merely being set in space. It is patterned after “soap opera” and has implications of melodrama and so forth. Is there any term for scifi set in space that isn’t a space opera?

Comment: When you say "in space" do you mean strictly off-planet (off _any_ planet), or merely not based primarily on Earth?  I.e. are you distinguishing between space opera and planetary romance?

Comment: "has implications of melodrama" ? Maybe originally, now that's just relatively soft sci-fi with hopping from one world to another. It's opposite is just hard sci-fi with realistic space travel.

Comment: Space Western is the obvious one

Comment: This is far too broad to be answered sensibly.

Comment: Anonymous, are you asking if there is a name for the complement of the set of space-themed science fiction stories that are not space opera? If so @Valorum, I think this is a pretty specific question. (The answer would be "No." Kinda in the same way that there isn't a name for literature that is not in the *Bildungsroman* genre.)

Comment: @epsben "Space opera" was originally coined in parallel with the existing "soap opera" or "horse opera", so "space western" can probably be rolled into space opera.